# React: set focus on componentDidMount, how to do it with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, with classes I can set the focus to an input when the component loads, something like this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    txt1 = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.txt1.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text"
                ref={e => this.txt1 = e}/>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite this component using the new [hooks proposal](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

I suppose I should use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) instead of `componentDidMount`, but how can I rewrite the focus logic?

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that it is also possible to set the autofocus property on the input itself without the need of JS like: `<input type="text" autofocus="true" />`. I know this is not a direct answer to your question, that's why I put it in a comment and I don't want to invalidate the given answer, I would do it the same way. I just think in many cases it's enough to just set the property directly and be done with it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to create a ref, and then focus it in a `useEffect` hook with an empty array as second argument to make sure it is only run after the initial render.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

function Foo() {
  const txt1 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    txt1.current.focus();
  }, []);

  return <input type="text" ref={txt1} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Why isn't `txt1` `null` when it's first called?

Comment: @notgiorgi The argument given to `useRef` is what value the ref's `current` property should be, so the initial value is `{ current: null }`. Giving an empty array as second argument to `useEffect` makes it so the effect is only run once after the initial render, which is what OP wanted.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I forgot that `useEffect` runs _after_ the initial render not _before_

Comment: This will throw a warning when using eslint "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'text1'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

Answer (score 0):

According to official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref
you can use `useRef`.

`useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (`initialValue`). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

A common use case is to access a child imperatively:

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Essentially, `useRef` is like a “box” that can hold a mutable value in its `.current` property.

You might be familiar with refs primarily as a way to access the DOM. If you pass a ref object to React with `<div ref={myRef} />`, React will set its `.current` property to the corresponding DOM node whenever that node changes.

However, `useRef()` is useful for more than the `ref` attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.

This works because `useRef()` creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference between `useRef()` and creating a `{current: ...}` object yourself is that useRef will give you the same ref object on every render.

Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the `.current` property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.