# Input loses focus on state change

Tags: reactjs

I have an input in a nested component. The state for that component is in its parent component. (The state can't be in the child component.) The problem is every input change, it loses focus, and the user has to click back on the input. I tried wrapping `SearchComponent` in `React.memo`, but it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**Parent Component**

```
const MainTable = props => {
const [myString, setMyString] = useState('');

const changeHandler = value => {
    setMyString(value);
}

<MyInputComponent
    changeHandler={changeHandler}
    myString={myString}
/>
```

**Nested Component**

```
const SearchComponent = props => {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');

    return (
        <input
            type='text'
            value={props.myString}
            onChange={e => {
                props.changeHandler(e.target.value);
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: use `ref` for focus, read docs

Comment: It is because you re-render your children everytime your parent component renders

Comment: I suppose you are not sharing the full code. Because when I try the code you have written in above, it works and not loosing focus.

Comment: @xadm Can you send a link to the docs?

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic Yes, that's the reason. But what's the sollution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188507/react-set-focus-on-componentdidmount-how-to-do-it-with-hooks

Comment: prepare [example]