# Auto-focus div on React form submit

Tags: html, reactjs

**EDIT**: Idk if the guy who helped me thought it was worth making an official answer (and I didn't want to steal his thunder by posting an answer myself) but here's my working **solution** (see comment section for details):
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/wad11656/pen/abJWRRJ)

I've been struggling to auto-`focus()` a `div` after a React form is submitted. I've tried using [useRef [SO link]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53188569/3511695)/[ref [SO link]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896228/3511695) as well as [componentDidMount() [SO link]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53188507/3511695) with no success. I'd like to be able to submit the form, then press Enter to close the `div` that appears afterwards. I am able to make the `div` appear on form-submit and have it so you can close the `div` by clicking on it and pressing Enter, but I want to bypass the need to click on the `div` first.

Below is the demonstration of what I'm trying to do. I've commented out my attempts at using `useRef`. Please run the code below to get a better visual of my goal.

In summary, how can I make a `div` auto-focus after a form submits? Thank you in advance

```js
//import useRef from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/useref@1.4.3";

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    //const myRef = useRef(null);
    this.state = { modal_enable: false
    }
  }
  submitForm = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    //myRef.current.focus()
    this.setState({ modal_enable: true })
  };
  closeModal = () => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey === false) {
    this.setState({ modal_enable: false })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { modal_enable } = this.state
    return (
      <div content>
<form onSubmit ={this.submitForm}>
  <input
    id='text_entry'
    type='text'
    placeholder='Cursor remains flashing inside this text box (i.e., focus remains here) after submitting by pressing Enter'
    />
      <input type='submit'/>
    </form>
            {modal_enable && (
            <div className="modal_box" onKeyDown={this.closeModal} tabIndex={0} /* ref={myRef} */>
        <p>Click inside me and press Enter to make me disappear. How can we make it so you don't have to click inside me first?</p>
            </div>
      )}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.modal_box {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#text_entry{
  width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using JavaScript focus() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

Comment: divs need a tabindex set to make them focusable

Comment: The div already has that. I can already successfully focus on the div, as the demo demonstrates. I need to auto-focus on the div when the form submits.

Comment: Oh. `setState` is async. Use the callback. `this.setState({ modal_enable: true }, () => myRef.current.focus())`.

Comment: Thank you -- In combination with your answer and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499129/3511695 I was able to get a working CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/wad11656/pen/abJWRRJ . Unfortunately I'm having trouble implementing it in my actual project :( But thank you for the solution

Comment: Never mind -- Successfully implemented in my project too...was just making a dumb mistake -- thanks!